# Where's the gnus info manual on Ubuntu?

Tags: gnus, info

I installed http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/emacs which includes Gnus, but there's no `/usr/share/info/gnus.info.gz` – am I forced to use the web wowser to read the fine manual, or is there some simple way to get the info file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the package database](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=zesty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gnus.info.gz), you can find `gnus.info.gz` in `emacs24-common-non-dfsg` and `/usr/share/info/emacs-25/gnus.info.gz`, along with a lot of other info manuals.

Comment: Correct. Debian (and Ubuntu by derivation) package Gnu documentation in separate packages, as the Gnu documentation license conflicts with the Debian Free Software Guidelines. Usually these packages are in the non-free repo, and have the `non-dfsg` suffix on the package name.